# Creating Lucky 7's game using raw Javascript, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

I've decided to come to the wise ones of stack overflow, in hopes of gaining some insight to my problem. I'm a newbie to javascript, and the school i'm attending has given us an assignment to create a Lucky 7's program.

The instructions are that a user places a bet, clicks play, and two dice are rolled. If the dice total is 7, $4 is added to the users bet, if not, $1 is subtracted.

Once the player reaches $0, a table showing the results is displayed. The results shown are "Starting Bet", "Total Rolls Before Going Broke", "Highest Amount Won", and "Roll count from Highest Amount Won".

So far I've got most of it working, but the results are always similar: All results are the same as the starting bet, except the highest amount won, that is always 1 less than the starting bet.

Could it have something to do with my while loop? I've tried moving things around and changing the assignment operators to `+=` instead of `bet = bet + 4`, but it's always the same. Any input would be much appreciated!

```
function hideResults() {
    document.getElementById("results").style.display = "none";
} 

function play() {
    var startingBet = document.getElementById("betInput").value;
    var bet = startingBet;
    var dice1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var diceRoll = dice1 + dice2;
    var betsArray = [];

    while (bet > 0) {
        if(diceRoll != 7) {
            bet -= 1
        } else { 
            bet += 4
        }
        betsArray.push(bet)
    }

    var rollCounter = betsArray.length;
    var highestAmount = Math.max.apply(Math, betsArray);
    var highestPosition = betsArray.indexOf(highestAmount);
    var rollsFromHighest = rollCounter - highestPosition;

    function showResults() {
    document.getElementById("results").style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById("playButton").innerHTML = "Play Again";
    document.getElementById("resultsBet").innerHTML = "$" + startingBet +".00";
    document.getElementById("resultsRollCounter").innerHTML = rollCounter;
    document.getElementById("resultsHighestHeld").innerHTML = "$" +     highestAmount + ".00";
    document.getElementById("resultsRollsFromHighest").innerHTML = rollsFromHighest;
    };

    showResults();
}
```

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lucky Sevens</title>
    <link href="css/LuckySevensStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/LuckySevensV1.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="hideResults()">

    <!-- BET STUFFS -->

<div id="gameDiv">
    <h1>Lucky Sevens</h1>
    <span>Starting Bet:<input type="number" name="Starting Bet" id="betInput" placeholder="$0.00"></span>
        <br/>
            <button onclick="play()" id="playButton">Play</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- RESULT STUFFS -->

    <div id="results">
        <table>
        <caption><h2>Results</h2></caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Starting Bet</th>
                <th id="resultsBet"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Rolls Before Going Broke</td>
                <td id="resultsRollCounter"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Highest Amount Won</td>
                <td id="resultsHighestHeld"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Roll Count at Highest Amount Won</td>
                <td id="resultsRollsFromHighest"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not re-rolling the dice within the while loop.

Comment: You never re roll the dice, and a maximum limit to the bet or the number of rolls would likely fix some of it I'm sure. Unless the point is to play until the player reaches $0

Comment: so the diceRoll within my loop doesn't reset after every loop? And the point is to play until the player reaches 0, then the results are displayed

Comment: ahhh so I should place the diceRoll outside of the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VARIABLE diceRoll  will not re calculate the random number.  You should reassign the random numbers within the loop after you push the updated bet to the array.

If you want, you could write a function to handle this, but it's just as easy to copy and paste your lines from the dice1 & dice2 and diceRoll var instantiations into the loop after the if block

Comment: okay so just because I have the diceRoll variable within the if statement that doesn't mean it will reset after each loop? I did what you suggested and now it looks like it's functioning properly, however instead of declaring the variables AFTER the if block I placed them before the if statement. Either way seemed to work, but is one way considered more appropriate than the other? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Doesn't matter before or after, just needs to be done in the loop.  If variables were reset to their initial values each time they were checked they would be useless indeed, so whenever you want them to update you have to reassign them explicitly

Comment: Ahh okay, I was thinking it would generate a random number each time. Thanks again!